# How can I animate specific views?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I want to animate **Bloc A to slide up** and **Bloc B to slide down** when I move from Activity 1 to Activity 2

Can someone bring me a solution for this ? Thanks a lot for your help

Here's an illustration of what I want :

[image]

Comment: Try the code below.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1) MainActivity.class:-------------

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Listener {

private Drawer m_Drawer;
private Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    m_Drawer = new Drawer(this, this);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b); // click on this button to open drawer.
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            m_Drawer.openDrawer();
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void AnimationFinished(int state) {
    if (state == 1) {
        b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // you can start a new activity or do whatever here.
    }else if(state == 0){
        b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

}
```

2) Drawer.class:-------

```
public class Drawer {

private static final String TAG = "Drawer";
private RelativeLayout topDrawer;//2
private RelativeLayout bottomDrawer;//2
private Activity activity;
private static final int DRAWER_UP = 1;
private static final int DRAWER_DOWN = 0;
private int mainlayoutHeight;
private TextView drawerTxt1;
private TextView drawerTxt;
private int direct;
private ConstraintLayout mainLayout;//1

private float mDownMotionX = 0;
private float mDownMotionY = 0;

private final int SWIPE_SENSITIVITY = 10;

private final int SWIPE_X_SENSITIVITY = 20;

private final int SWIPE_Y_SENSITIVITY_MIN = 0;
private int SWIPE_Y_SENSITIVITY_MAX = 0;

private Listener callback;

Drawer(Activity mainActivity , Listener l) {
    activity = mainActivity;
    if(l != null){
        this.callback = l;
    }
    initialize();
    getLayoutHeight();

}

private void initialize() {

    topDrawer =  (RelativeLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.top_drawer);//2
    drawerTxt1 = (TextView) topDrawer.findViewById(R.id.drawer_txt1);
    drawerTxt1.setText("BLOCK A");
    bottomDrawer =  (RelativeLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.bottom_drawer);//2
    drawerTxt = (TextView) bottomDrawer.findViewById(R.id.drawer_txt);
    drawerTxt.setText("BLOCK B");

    topDrawer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Touch View");
            final int action = ev.getAction();

            switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Remember where the motion event started
                    mDownMotionX = ev.getX();
                    mDownMotionY = ev.getY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    // Scroll to follow the motion event
                    final float x = ev.getX();
                    final float y = ev.getY();

                    SWIPE_Y_SENSITIVITY_MAX = getScreenHeight();

                    if (Math.abs(y - mDownMotionY) >= SWIPE_SENSITIVITY &&
                            (mDownMotionY > SWIPE_Y_SENSITIVITY_MIN &&
                                    mDownMotionY <= SWIPE_Y_SENSITIVITY_MAX) &&
                            Math.abs(x - mDownMotionX) <= SWIPE_X_SENSITIVITY) {

                        if ((y - mDownMotionY) > 0) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Dragging Down");
                        }
                    } else if ((y - mDownMotionY) < 0) {
                        closeDrawer();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Dragging Up");
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    bottomDrawer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Touch View");
            final int action = ev.getAction();

            switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Remember where the motion event started
                    mDownMotionX = ev.getX();
                    mDownMotionY = ev.getY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    // Scroll to follow the motion event
                    final float x = ev.getX();
                    final float y = ev.getY();

                    SWIPE_Y_SENSITIVITY_MAX = getScreenHeight();

                    if (Math.abs(y - mDownMotionY) >= SWIPE_SENSITIVITY &&
                            (mDownMotionY > SWIPE_Y_SENSITIVITY_MIN &&
                                    mDownMotionY <= SWIPE_Y_SENSITIVITY_MAX) &&
                            Math.abs(x - mDownMotionX) <= SWIPE_X_SENSITIVITY) {

                        if ((y - mDownMotionY) > 0) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Dragging Down");
                            closeDrawer();
                        }
                    } else if ((y - mDownMotionY) < 0) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Dragging Up");
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });


}

//********************************************************************************************** Open and Close the Drawer /Animation/
private void drawerMovement(int movement){
    switch (movement) {
        case DRAWER_UP: // --------------------------------------------------------------------- Drawer UP
            topDrawer.animate().translationY(-mainlayoutHeight/2); // you can add two animation listeners, but for now one is enough.
            bottomDrawer.animate().translationY(mainlayoutHeight)
                    .setListener(new animationListener());
            direct = DRAWER_UP;
            break;

        case DRAWER_DOWN: // ------------------------------------------------------------------- Drawer DOWN
            topDrawer.animate().translationY(0);
            bottomDrawer.animate().translationY(mainlayoutHeight/2)
                    .setListener(new animationListener());
            direct = DRAWER_DOWN;
            break;
    }
}

//**********************************************************************************************  Animation Listener
private class animationListener implements  Animator.AnimatorListener {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        callback.AnimationFinished(direct);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
}

private void closeDrawer(){
    drawerMovement(DRAWER_UP);
}

public void openDrawer(){
    drawerMovement(DRAWER_DOWN);
}

// ********************************************************************************************* Get the Layout Height
private void getLayoutHeight() {
    mainLayout = (ConstraintLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);//1
    ViewTreeObserver vto = mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            mainlayoutHeight = mainLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
            topDrawer.setY(0);
            bottomDrawer.setY(mainlayoutHeight/2);
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mainlayoutHeight/2);//1
            topDrawer.setLayoutParams(params);
            bottomDrawer.setLayoutParams(params);
            Log.d("Test", "Layout Height: " + mainlayoutHeight );
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
}

private int getScreenHeight(){

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    return displayMetrics.heightPixels;
}

}
```

3) Listener interface:----------

```
public interface Listener {

public void AnimationFinished(int state);

}
```

4) main_activity.xml:----------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_drawer"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_txt"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/top_drawer"
    android:background="?attr/colorAccent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_txt1"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:text="Open Drawer"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help man, I really appreciate it! However I've got this error `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams`because I use in my xml RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout for top_drawer and bottom_drawer.

Comment: Change private LinearLayout topDrawer and private LinearLayout bottomDrawer variable types to RelativeLayout.

Comment: The above variables are in the Drawer class.

Comment: I updated the answer with RelativeLayouts instead of LinearLayouts for top_drawer and bottom_drawer. If this answer was helpful than please accept it. Thank you.

Comment: I tested it myself and it is working. Are you getting any error?

Comment: Yes I got the previous error I mentionned above. I didn't put </include> in my xml. I directly put the content of it inside main_activity.xml. Is it a problem ?

Comment: That was my bad because I want to wrap top_drawner and bottom_drawner inside a LinearLayout ? Is it possible ? If yes what must I change in my code to make it work  ?

Comment: No. It is better if top_drawer and bottom_drawer remain separated.

Comment: What if I use constraint layout instead of relative layout (container of xml) ? Thanks for helping me Rabee

Comment: Do you mean the parent layout or all layouts (for top and bottom drawers also)?

Comment: The Parent layout is now the Constraint layout

Comment: Do you want me to tell you what do you need to change?

Comment: I edited my answer: replaced RelativeLayout with ConstraintLayout. I have also marked mainLayout and things related to it with 1. Also marked top_drawer and bottom_drawer and things related to them with 2. So every time you need to update parent (main layout) or (top and bottom drawers), you need to change their corresponding code as marked above (1 or 2).

Comment: Thanks. I test it but it doesn't work. Bloc_b goes on the top and Bloc A disepear without click on anything. Why don't you use the Animation api provided by Android ? I've already tested it but it doesn't work at all. Maybe you could help me to know why. Here's code I tried : `Slide topTransition = new Slide();
        topTransition.addTarget(top_drawner);
        topTransition.setSlideEdge(Gravity.TOP);
        getWindow().setExitTransition(topTransition);`

Comment: This is the output of the code above [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rmx9RKNrmw5Y08yca4oWXYk7pdAQ8bDY/view?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rmx9RKNrmw5Y08yca4oWXYk7pdAQ8bDY/view?usp=sharing)